# Storing Collective Level Score Values For An Overall "Bank" Value in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nskeyedarchiver, key-value-store

I have a game that has 9 different levels which have their own highscore values for coins collected and special coins collected. I want to make a "Bank" that can store those values and add them up to be able to 'purchase' the unlock for some levels. I'm not sure if I implemented my scoring system in a way that won't allow this or if I'm missing something simple. Any insight is greatly appreciated!

```
import Foundation

struct ScoreManager {

static func getCurrentScore(for levelKey: String) -> [String:Int] {
    if let existingData = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: levelKey) as? [String:Int] {
        return existingData
    } else  {
        return [GameConstants.StringConstants.scoreScoreKey:0, GameConstants.StringConstants.scoreStarsKey:0, GameConstants.StringConstants.scoreCoinsKey:0]
    }
}

static func updateScore(for levelKey: String, and score: [String:Int]) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(score, forKey: levelKey)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

}

static func compare(scores: [[String:Int]], in levelKey: String) {

    var newHighscore = false
    let currentScore = getCurrentScore(for: levelKey)

    var maxScore = currentScore[GameConstants.StringConstants.scoreScoreKey]!
    var maxStars = currentScore[GameConstants.StringConstants.scoreStarsKey]!
    var maxCoins = currentScore[GameConstants.StringConstants.scoreCoinsKey]!

    for score in scores {
        if score[GameConstants.StringConstants.scoreScoreKey]! > maxScore {
            maxScore = score[GameConstants.StringConstants.scoreScoreKey]!
            newHighscore = true
        }
        if score[GameConstants.StringConstants.scoreStarsKey]! > maxStars {
            maxStars = score[GameConstants.StringConstants.scoreStarsKey]!
            newHighscore = true
        }
        if score[GameConstants.StringConstants.scoreCoinsKey]! > maxCoins {
            maxCoins = score[GameConstants.StringConstants.scoreCoinsKey]!
            newHighscore = true
        }

    }

    if newHighscore {

        let newScore = [GameConstants.StringConstants.scoreScoreKey: maxScore, GameConstants.StringConstants.scoreStarsKey: maxStars, GameConstants.StringConstants.scoreCoinsKey: maxCoins]

        updateScore(for: levelKey, and: newScore)

    }

}
```

And this is called in the GameScene after you finish the level..

```
func finishGame() {
    gameState = .finished
    var stars = 0
    let percentage = CGFloat(coins)/100.0
    if percentage >= 0.8 {
        stars = 3
    } else if percentage >= 0.4 {
        stars = 2
    } else if coins >= 1 {
        stars = 1
    }
    let scores = [
        GameConstants.StringConstants.scoreScoreKey: coins,
        GameConstants.StringConstants.scoreStarsKey: stars,
        GameConstants.StringConstants.scoreCoinsKey: superCoins

    ]


    ScoreManager.compare(scores: [scores], in: levelKey)
    createAndShowPopup(type: 1, title: GameConstants.StringConstants.completedKey)

    if level < 9 {
        let nextLevelKey = "Level_\(world)-\(level+1)_Unlocked"

        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: nextLevelKey)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}
```

Ignore the stars, I used these to show basically how well you did on the level. I'll gladly provide more code snippets if needed too. Thank you all again!

Comment: What is the problem here

Comment: So I can store my coins high score values for each level separately, but I'm trying to figure out a way to store those values together to make a sort of "Bank". Say for example the player gets 100 coins on level one and 200 on level two, and level three costs 300 coins to unlock, how do I store the first two level's high score values together to give the user a "Bank". I know I'll need another node to present it, but the problem is getting those values to add together, a little confusing but hopefully it makes a little sense. Thanks for responding @Knight0fDragon, always coming through!

Comment: lol,  have you thought about using a new key called "bank" to store in your UserDefaults, and when you save the coins on completing level 1, you add it to both the local key and the bank key?

Comment: Something like `let bank = UserDefaults.standard.get(forKey: "bank") as! Int; bank += coins; UserDefaults.standard.set(bank, forKey:"bank") `

Comment: Wow lol, I did try the bank key but didn't try the bank += coins, very nice, I'll give this a try. Thanks mate!!